# How to define a checkbox with image, and a custom icon

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I want to create a CheckBox that I can use a custom icon for the check and unchecked icons. but also then have an image instead of text as the main part of the CheckBox.
I.e., like this, but with the background image offset to the left, or moveable like the text is if Image was Text.

```
box.Image = Image.FromFile("myimage.jpg");

box.CheckStateChanged += new System.EventHandler(Checkbox_CheckStateChanged);
private void Checkbox_CheckStateChanged(CheckBox box, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (box.CheckState)
            {
                case CheckState.Checked:
                    box.Image = CheckedImage;
                    break;
                case CheckState.Unchecked:
                    box.Image = UnCheckedImage;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are we talking about Winforms or WPF?

Comment: @Blachshma I tagged it winforms because using `System.EvenHandler` seems to indicate this is the most likely.

Comment: its winforms or devcomponents. .net 2