# how to change the check image on a checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox

it has text, an image, and then the checkbox,

I want to use a better image for the check, but cannot find a way to change the checked and unchecked images

```
this.checkBox1.CheckAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
this.checkBox1.Checked = true;
this.checkBox1.CheckState = System.Windows.Forms.CheckState.Checked;
this.checkBox1.Image = global::ClientExam.Properties.Resources.action32;
this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(145, 140);
this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(273, 127);
this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 0;
this.checkBox1.Text = "checkBox1";
this.checkBox1.TextImageRelation = System.Windows.Forms.TextImageRelation.TextBeforeImage;
this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

anybody know of one that doesn't require me to write my own control?

Comment: its winforms, And I know i can write my own control or override to do it, but i didnt want to reinvent the wheel, as it seems like the sort of thing someone else would have already written.
I have all the DevComponents but they also dont seem to have one, least not one im aware of.

Anyone know of a component that can do this out the box?

Comment: This is related to an earlier question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124813/how-to-define-a-checkbox-with-image-and-a-custom-icon

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are looking for how to do this in Winforms, the simple answer is to create a new checkbox class that derives from CheckBox, then override the [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) method.

Here is an example on how to create custom looking checkboxes by overriding the `OnPaint` method:

```
public class CustomCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public CustomCheckBox()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pevent);
        if (this.Checked)
        {
            pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));
        }
        else
        {
            pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));
        }
    }
}
```

It's very simple, but it gives you the basic idea.

Answer (score 24):

For anyone who'd prefer not to override OnPaint, there's an alternative solution:

1. Add an `ImageList` control and fill it with images to reflect checked/unchecked states.
2. Set your `Checkbox` control's `Appearance` property to `Button` (to get rid of standard CheckBox icon)
3. Set its' `FlatStyle` property to `Flat` (so that the control doesn't really look like a button).
   Note: You may want to check its' `FlatAppearance` group of properties too. Namely `CheckedBackColor`, `MouseDownBackColor`, `MouseOverBackColor`, i.e. set them all to `Control` value.
4. Set `Checkbox` control's `ImageList` property to the name of your `ImageList` control.
5. Set `Checkbox` control's `Imageindex` and `ImageAlign` properties to reflect its' current state.
6. Last and most importantly set `Checkbox` control's `TextImageRelation` property (this value won't let the text and image overlap unless you want them to). I.e. `ImageBeforetext` value represents common CheckBox icon location.

Now the only thing left to do is to change the image when the state is changed, smth like this:

```
    private void chkMyCheckBoxWithAnImage_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkMyCheckBoxWithAnImage.Checked)
            chkMyCheckBoxWithAnImage.ImageIndex = 1;
        else
            chkMyCheckBoxWithAnImage.ImageIndex = 0;
    }
```

Comment: In my opinion this should be the answer.  The other answer doesn't mention that you have to handle drawing the text in addition to the images.

Comment: You can do exactly the same thing without the image list just by setting the image property directly in the CheckedChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

A simple one :

overrides  check box `OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)` as below:

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        base.OnPaint(e);
        //// Fill the background
        //SetControlSizes();

        // Paint the outer rounded rectangle
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        using (GraphicsPath outerPath = GeneralUtilities.RoundedRectangle(mLabelRect, 1, 0))
        {
            using (LinearGradientBrush outerBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(mLabelRect,
                   mGradientTop, mGradientBottom, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
            {
                g.FillPath(outerBrush, outerPath);
            }
            using (Pen outlinePen = new Pen(mGradientTop, mRectOutlineWidth))
            {
                outlinePen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
                g.DrawPath(outlinePen, outerPath);
            }
        }

        //// Paint the gel highlight
        using (GraphicsPath innerPath = GeneralUtilities.RoundedRectangle(mHighlightRect, mRectCornerRadius, mHighlightRectOffset))
        {
            using (LinearGradientBrush innerBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(mHighlightRect,
                   Color.FromArgb(mHighlightAlphaTop, Color.White),
                   Color.FromArgb(mHighlightAlphaBottom, Color.White), LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
            {
                g.FillPath(innerBrush, innerPath);
            }
        }
        // Paint the text
        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, Text, Font, mLabelRect, Color.White, Color.Transparent,
        TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis);
```

But if you want to have a good one you have to use [wpf CheckBox ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have got around this a different way, I use the background image and center it, then change the main image whenever checked is changed.
this appears like I want it to.

There is a problem with this, the background image if an inappropriate size with underlap the check image, and so it would not look right.

the correct solution is as icemanind describes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Custom CheckBox]

Complete custom CheckBox control that support theming

1. Predefined styles (VS 2019 Dark and Light).
2. Support for AutoSize property.
3. Support for custom colors in focused, mouse enter and mouse down events.
4. Support for custom check mark (shape and color).
5. Public properties to customize the look the CheckBox control.

   ```
   'Copyright (c) Smart PC Utilities, Ltd.
   'All rights reserved.

   #Region "References"

   Imports System.ComponentModel
   Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

   #End Region

   Namespace FlatUI

   ''' <summary>
   ''' Flat CheckBox control
   ''' </summary>
   Public NotInheritable Class FlatCheckBox
       Inherits CheckBox

   #Region "Private Members"

       Dim _theme As UITheme = UITheme.LightBlue

       Private _boxNormalBackColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(243, 249, 255)
       Private _boxFocusBackColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(243, 249, 255)
       Private _boxMouseDownBackColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255)

       Private _boxNormalBorderColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30)
       Private _boxFocusBorderColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255)
       Private _boxMouseDownBorderColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255)

       Private _checkMarkNormalColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30)
       Private _checkMarkFocusColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30)
       Private _checkMarkMouseDownColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(243, 249, 255)

       Private _focusCuesColor As Color = Color.Gray

       Private _isMouseEnter As Boolean
       Private _isMouseDown As Boolean

   #End Region

   #Region "Constants"

       Const TEXT_X = 21
       Const TEXT_Y = 2

       Const BOX_X = 4
       Const BOX_Y = 4

       Const BOX_WIDTH = 12
       Const BOX_HEIGHT = 12

   #End Region

   #Region "Public Methods"

       Public Sub New()

           SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)

           BackColor = Color.FromArgb(251, 251, 251)
           ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30)
           Appearance = Appearance.Button
           FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
           FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
           DoubleBuffered = True
           UseVisualStyleBackColor = False

       End Sub

   #End Region

   #Region "Public Properties"

       <Localizable(True)> <Category("Flat CheckBox")> <Description("The box backcolor in the normal state.")> <DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "243, 249, 255")>
       Public Property BoxNormalBackColor As Color
           Get
               Return _boxNormalBackColor
           End Get
           Set(value As Color)
               _boxNormalBackColor = value
               Invalidate()
           End Set
       End Property

       <Localizable(True)> <Category("Flat CheckBox")> <Description("The box backcolor when the CheckBox control is focused.")> <DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "243, 249, 255")>
       Public Property BoxFocusBackColor As Color
           Get
               Return _boxFocusBackColor
           End Get
           Set(value As Color)
               _boxFocusBackColor = value
               Invalidate()
           End Set
       End Property

       <Localizable(True)> <Category("Flat CheckBox")> <Description("The box backcolor when the CheckBox control is clicked.")> <DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "51, 153, 255")>
       Public Property BoxMouseDownBackColor As Color
           Get
               Return _boxMouseDownBackColor
           End Get
           Set(value As Color)
               _boxMouseDownBackColor = value
               Invalidate()
           End Set
       End Property

       <Localizable(True)> <Category("Flat CheckBox")> <Description("The box border color in the normal state.")> <DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "30, 30, 30")>
       Public Property BoxNormalBorderColor As Color
           Get
               Return _boxNormalBorderColor
           End Get
           Set(value As Color)
               _boxNormalBorderColor = value
               Invalidate()
           End Set
       End Property

       <Localizable(True)> <Category("Flat CheckBox")> <Description("The box border color when the CheckBox control is focused.")> <DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "51, 153, 255")>
       Public Property BoxFocusBorderColor As Color
           Get
               Return _boxFocusBorderColor
           End Get
           Set(value As Color)
               _boxFocusBorderColor = value
               Invalidate()
           End Set
       End Property

       <Localizable(True)> <Category("Flat CheckBox")> <Description("The box border color when the CheckBox control is clicked.")> <DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "51, 153, 255")>
       Public Property BoxMouseDownBorderColor As Color
           Get
               Return _boxMouseDownBorderColor
           End Get
           Set(value As Color)
               _boxMouseDownBorderColor = value
               Invalidate()
           End Set
       End Property

       <Localizable(True)> <Category("Flat CheckBox")> <Description("The CheckBox check-mark color in the normal state.")> <DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "30, 30, 30")>
       Public Property CheckMarkNormalColor As Color
           Get
               Return _checkMarkNormalColor
           End Get
           Set(value As Color)
               _checkMarkNormalColor = value
               Invalidate()
           End Set
       End Property

       <Localizable(True)> <Category("Flat CheckBox")> <Description("The CheckBox check-mark color when the CheckBox control is focused.")> <DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "30, 30, 30")>
       Public Property CheckMarkFocusColor As Color
           Get
               Return _checkMarkFocusColor
           End Get
           Set(value As Color)
               _checkMarkFocusColor = value
               Invalidate()
           End Set
       End Property

       <Localizable(True)> <Category("Flat CheckBox")> <Description("The CheckBox check-mark color when the CheckBox control is clicked.")> <DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "243, 249, 255")>
       Public Property CheckMarkMouseDownColor As Color
           Get
               Return _checkMarkMouseDownColor
           End Get
           Set(value As Color)
               _checkMarkMouseDownColor = value
               Invalidate()
           End Set
       End Property

       <Localizable(True)> <Category("Flat CheckBox")> <Description("The CheckBox control focus cues color.")> <DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "Gray")>
       Public Property FocusCuesColor As Color
           Get
               Return _focusCuesColor
           End Get
           Set(value As Color)
               _focusCuesColor = value
               Invalidate()
           End Set
       End Property

       <Category("Flat CheckBox")> <Description("The general style of the Flat CheckBox control.")> <DefaultValue(GetType(UITheme), "1")> Public Property Theme As UITheme
           Get
               Return _theme
           End Get
           Set(value As UITheme)
               _theme = value

               If _theme = UITheme.DarkBlue Then

                   BackColor = Color.FromArgb(37, 37, 38)
                   ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro
                   BoxNormalBackColor = Color.FromArgb(31, 31, 32)
                   BoxFocusBackColor = Color.FromArgb(31, 31, 32)
                   BoxMouseDownBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204)
                   BoxNormalBorderColor = Color.Gainsboro
                   BoxFocusBorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204)
                   BoxMouseDownBorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204)
                   CheckMarkNormalColor = Color.FromArgb(241, 241, 241)
                   CheckMarkFocusColor = Color.FromArgb(241, 241, 241)
                   CheckMarkMouseDownColor = Color.FromArgb(241, 241, 241)
                   FocusCuesColor = Color.Gray

               ElseIf _theme = UITheme.LightBlue Then

                   BackColor = Color.FromArgb(251, 251, 251)
                   ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30)
                   BoxNormalBackColor = Color.FromArgb(243, 249, 255)
                   BoxFocusBackColor = Color.FromArgb(243, 249, 255)
                   BoxMouseDownBackColor = Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255)
                   BoxNormalBorderColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30)
                   BoxFocusBorderColor = Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255)
                   BoxMouseDownBorderColor = Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255)
                   CheckMarkNormalColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30)
                   CheckMarkFocusColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30)
                   CheckMarkMouseDownColor = Color.FromArgb(243, 249, 255)
                   FocusCuesColor = Color.Gray

               End If

               Invalidate()

           End Set
       End Property

   #End Region

   #Region "Private Methods"

       Private Sub ResizeForAutoSize()
           If AutoSize Then SetBoundsCore(Left, Top, Width, Height, BoundsSpecified.Size)
       End Sub

       Private Function GetAutoSize() As Size

           Dim g = CreateGraphics()
           Dim textSize = g.MeasureString(Text, Font)
           Dim cntrlSize As New Size(CInt(textSize.Width + TEXT_X), CInt(textSize.Height + (TEXT_Y * 2)))

           Return cntrlSize

       End Function

   #End Region

   #Region "Overridden Methods"

       Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)

   #Disable Warning CA1062 ' Validate arguments of public methods
           e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
   #Enable Warning CA1062 ' Validate arguments of public methods
           e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor)

           'Draw CheckBox text

           Using b As New SolidBrush(ForeColor)
               e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, b, TEXT_X, TEXT_Y)
           End Using

           'Draw box background

           Dim boxBackgroundColor As Color

           If _isMouseDown Then
               boxBackgroundColor = _boxMouseDownBackColor
           ElseIf Focused OrElse _isMouseEnter Then
               boxBackgroundColor = _boxFocusBackColor
           Else
               boxBackgroundColor = _boxNormalBackColor
           End If

           Using b As New SolidBrush(boxBackgroundColor)
               e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, BOX_X, BOX_Y, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT)
           End Using

           'Draw check mark

           If Checked Then

               Dim checkMarkColor As Color

               If _isMouseDown Then
                   checkMarkColor = _checkMarkMouseDownColor
               ElseIf Focused OrElse _isMouseEnter Then
                   checkMarkColor = _checkMarkFocusColor
               Else
                   checkMarkColor = _checkMarkNormalColor
               End If

               Dim rectCheck = New Rectangle(BOX_X + 2, BOX_Y + 3, BOX_WIDTH - 4, BOX_HEIGHT - 6)

               Using p = New Pen(checkMarkColor, 2)
                   e.Graphics.DrawLines(p, New Point() {New Point(rectCheck.Left, rectCheck.Bottom - CInt(rectCheck.Height / 2)), New Point(rectCheck.Left + CInt(rectCheck.Width / 3), rectCheck.Bottom), New Point(rectCheck.Right, rectCheck.Top)})
               End Using

           End If

           'Draw box border

           Dim boxBorderColor As Color

           If _isMouseDown Then
               boxBorderColor = _boxMouseDownBorderColor
           ElseIf Focused OrElse _isMouseEnter Then
               boxBorderColor = _boxFocusBorderColor
           Else
               boxBorderColor = _boxNormalBorderColor
           End If

           Using p = New Pen(boxBorderColor)
               e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, BOX_X, BOX_Y, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT)
           End Using

           'Draw focus cues

           If Focused Then

               Dim textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(Text, Font)

               Dim focusRect = New Rectangle(TEXT_X - 1, TEXT_Y - 1, CInt(textSize.Width), CInt(textSize.Height))
               focusRect.Inflate(-1, -1)

               Using p As New Pen(_focusCuesColor) With {.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot}
                   e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.Default
                   e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, focusRect)
               End Using

           End If

           ResizeForAutoSize()

       End Sub

       Public Overrides Function GetPreferredSize(proposedSize As Size) As Size
           Return GetAutoSize()
       End Function

       Protected Overrides Sub SetBoundsCore(x As Integer, y As Integer, width As Integer, height As Integer, specified As BoundsSpecified)

           If AutoSize AndAlso (specified And BoundsSpecified.Size) <> 0 Then
               Dim cntrlSize = GetAutoSize()
               width = cntrlSize.Width
               height = cntrlSize.Height
           End If

           MyBase.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, height, specified)

       End Sub

       Protected Overrides Sub OnResize(e As EventArgs)
           MyBase.OnResize(e)
           Invalidate()
       End Sub

       Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseEnter(eventargs As EventArgs)

           MyBase.OnMouseEnter(eventargs)

           _isMouseEnter = True
           Invalidate()

       End Sub

       Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeave(eventargs As EventArgs)

           MyBase.OnMouseLeave(eventargs)

           _isMouseEnter = False
           Invalidate()

       End Sub

       Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(mevent As MouseEventArgs)

           MyBase.OnMouseDown(mevent)

           _isMouseDown = True
           Invalidate()

       End Sub

       Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseUp(mevent As MouseEventArgs)

           MyBase.OnMouseUp(mevent)

           _isMouseDown = False
           Invalidate()

       End Sub

       <DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "251, 251, 251")> Public Overrides Property BackColor As Color
           Get
               Return MyBase.BackColor
           End Get
           Set(value As Color)
               MyBase.BackColor = value
           End Set
       End Property

       <DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "30, 30, 30")> Public Overrides Property ForeColor As Color
           Get
               Return MyBase.ForeColor
           End Get
           Set(value As Color)
               MyBase.ForeColor = value
           End Set
       End Property

   #End Region

   End Class

   End Namespace
   ```

Themes enumeration

```
'Copyright (c) Smart PC Utilities, Ltd.
'All rights reserved.

Namespace FlatUI

    Public Enum UITheme As Integer

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Undefined style
        ''' </summary>
        Undefined = -1

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Visual Studio 2019 Dark style
        ''' </summary>
        DarkBlue = 0

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Visual Studio 2019 Light style
        ''' </summary>
        LightBlue = 1

    End Enum

End Namespace
```