# C# WinForms: Make CheckBox look like a RadioButton

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, checkbox

Actually on a WinForms project (VS 2010, C#, .NET 4.5), I build a matrix (10x10) in a form. Each element is represented by a control that can be "checked" or "unchecked". Each element's state is completely independent of another.

The ideal solution would be to use a CheckBox. Unfortunately, the client wants a different appearance - for example, the one of the RadioButton. I could use RadioButton, place every one of them in a dedicated group, add an event listener to uncheck on-click if the element is already checked... Pretty much for a question of appearance!

Couldn't I override some rendering methods of CheckBox class? (Anyway, that's the only place in the whole application where I use this control)

Note: Controls are instanciated on runtime from a class MyClass:CheckBox.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15813869/11683

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a RadioButton if you need to make it look like one.  You'll need to set their AutoCheck property to False to make them act like check boxes and give them a common event handler:

```
    private void radioButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var button = (RadioButton)sender;
        button.Checked = !button.Checked;
    }
```

Never hesitate to point out that this is very poor UI design.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. Of course, the most eligible solution is social and should be to convince my client that each control has its own function :) Yet your answer works as well. Thanks