# C# Checkbox style image

Tags: c#, image, winforms, checkbox

Is there any posibility to create an image that acts like a checkbox? Or to style a checkbox by replacing it with 2 images, one for unchecked and one for checked? I haven't found anything similar. Thanks :)

Comment: To answer your question, sure.  Have you searched at all?  Plenty of solutions available.

Comment: Are you talking about WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or something else entirely?

Comment: The answer is `yes` to both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change the check image on a checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813869/how-to-change-the-check-image-on-a-checkbox)

Comment: I already seen that, if that was good for me, I didn't post this question ;) WinForms

Comment: @B.K. how can I do that?

Comment: How would we know if you'd seen that before? Update your question with that information and the appropriate tags. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: It really is very simple: switch the images in the checkchanged event. one simple way is to use an imagelist and set the imageindex. much easier than coding the paint event.. - Also Please do explain what you don't liek about the thing you found!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CheckBoxImage : PictureBox
{
    private bool cchecked;
    private Image ci;
    public Image CheckedImage
    {
         get
         {
             return ci;
         }
         set
         {
             ci = value;
         }
    }
    private Image uci;
    public Image UnCheckedImage
    {
        get
        {
            return uci;
        }
        set
        {
           uci = value;
        }
    }
    public bool Checked
    {
        get
        {
            return cchecked;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                Image = CheckedImage;
            }
            else
            {
                Image = UnCheckedImage;
            }
            cchecked = value;
        }
    }
    public CheckBoxImage(Image checkedimage, Image uncheckedimage)
    {
        CheckedImage = checkedimage;
        UnCheckedImage = uncheckedimage;
        Click += (sender, e) => { Checked = !Checked; };
    }
}
```

I think this should do. Just place it on the form the same way you would with a normal PictureBox.

Comment: make the Images properties! - Why not derive from checkbox??

Comment: Because applying an image to a checkbox would be a lot more hassle than this I imagine. And yes, I realised the properties thing just now when I was using Visual Studio, I'll edit this thing immediately.