# Windows Forms Button: Disable text shifting when pressed

Tags: winforms, winapi

I would like to self-draw the checkmark of a Checkbox, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252382/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-check-mark-of-a-checkbox/35252891).

This requires setting the CheckBox to `checkBox.Appearance = Appearance.Button` and then disabling the borders. Meaning, the CheckBox is now rendered as if it was a button. When it is checked, it is rendered as a depressed button.

Unfortunately, a depressed button has its text shifted slightly to the right and downwards. This behaviour is not commonly seen in a CheckBox.

[image: Our CheckBox with Appearance set to "Button"]

```
var cb = new Checkbox();
cb.Paint += delegate (object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Here you can custom-draw the Checkmark.
    // (but I'd like to fix the text-shifting first)
};
cb.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
cb.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
cb.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
cb.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
```

Is it possible to configure a Button (or a CheckBox configured as Button) so that the text is not shifted when it is being depressed?

Comment: No, it is [hard-coded](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonInternal/ButtonFlatAdapter.cs,294) against the button state.

Comment: You can always derive your own Custom Control from Button or CheckBox and draw whatever you need, text or graphic, as *shifted* or not *shifted* as you please.

Comment: You don't need to set it to the button style, just paint the control yourself, for example look at the customization [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38432140/3110834).