# How to Create bigger CheckBox

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: Checkbox]

I want to design above screen in windows forms. When I am tried to use checkbox control the size of the box is not increasing.

I tried below code but checkbox color and bored color is not changing.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyCheckBox : CheckBox {
    public MyCheckBox() {
        this.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    }
    public override bool AutoSize {
        get { return base.AutoSize; }
        set { base.AutoSize = false; }
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        int h = this.ClientSize.Height - 2;
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 1), new Size(h, h));
        ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, rc,
            this.Checked ? ButtonState.Checked : ButtonState.Normal);
    }
}
```

RadioButton also tried but I don't know how to apply colors and highlight the text.

Comment: The sizes of checkboxes and radio buttons are determined by the theme. Changing the size of the rectangle you draw one in will not change the size of the control

Comment: Did your images come from a website?  Different technology.  WinForms uses the CheckBoxRenderer.  ControlPaint is old.

Comment: when I am increasing checkbox text size, the box size is very small. I have to increase my checkbox box size.

Comment: I need to design in windows forms only. I should not use any images

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: sorry LarsTech I did not understood your question

Comment: Where are those images you have in your question coming from?

Comment: those images are Wireframes

Comment: WPF would make this easier.  In WinForms, you would have to draw things yourself.  What's wrong with your code?  It draws a bigger CheckBox.

Comment: We are not using WPF. Yes its draws bigger checkbox. But the box color is coming as white. I need to keep it as background color "black and border color as white.

Comment: Then you are just going to have to draw the whole thing yourself since you have a very custom specification.

Comment: The code draws big checkboxes alright. just make surethe height is indeed large enough. I think you'll also have to draw the rest of the checkbox..

Comment: If limited to C# and not able to add images, then you will need to owner draw your check box and make the squares yourself. it's not hard. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813869/how-to-change-the-check-image-on-a-checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsForms
{
   public class BiggerCheckBox : CheckBox
   {
        #region variables
        private int _boxsize = 14;
        private int _boxlocatx = 0;
        private int _boxlocaty = 0;
        private int _textX = 16;
        private int _textY = 1;
        private Color _boxBackColor = Color.Transparent;
        private Color _tickColor = Color.Black;
        private float _tickSize = 11f;
        private Color _boxColor = Color.Black;
        private float _tickLeftPosition = 0f;
        private float _tickTopPosition = 0f;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public int TextLocationX
        {
            get { return _textX; }
            set { _textX = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public int TextLocationY
        {
            get { return _textY; }
            set { _textY = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public int BoxSize
        {
            get { return _boxsize; }
            set { _boxsize = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public int BoxLocationX
        {
            get { return _boxlocatx; }
            set { _boxlocatx = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public int BoxLocationY
        {
            get { return _boxlocaty; }
            set { _boxlocaty = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public Color BoxBackColor
        {
            get { return _boxBackColor; }
            set { _boxBackColor = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public Color TickColor
        {
            get { return _tickColor; }
            set { _tickColor = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public float TickSize
        {
            get { return _tickSize; }
            set { _tickSize = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public Color BoxColor
        {
            get { return _boxColor; }
            set { _boxColor = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public float TickLeftPosition
        {
            get { return _tickLeftPosition; }
            set { _tickLeftPosition = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public float TickTopPosition
        {
            get { return _tickTopPosition; }
            set { _tickTopPosition = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constrctors
        public BiggerCheckBox()
        {
            Appearance = Appearance.Button;
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            AutoSize = false;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnPaint(pevent);
                pevent.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);

                //checkbox text - using draw string method with specified location
                using (SolidBrush brushText = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
                {
                    pevent.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brushText, _textX, _textY);
                }

                //checkbox box -  using rectangle for checkbox box
                Rectangle _rectangleBox = new Rectangle(_boxlocatx, _boxlocaty, _boxsize, _boxsize);

                //checkbox box -  checckbox box back color and border color
                using (SolidBrush brushBackColor = new SolidBrush(_boxBackColor))
                {
                    pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(brushBackColor, _rectangleBox);
                }
                using (Pen penBoxColor = new Pen(_boxColor))
                {
                    pevent.Graphics.DrawRectangle(penBoxColor, _rectangleBox);
                }

                //checkbox box -  check and uncheck
                if (Checked)
                {
                    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(_tickColor))
                    {
                        using (Font wing = new Font("Wingdings", _tickSize))
                        {
                            pevent.Graphics.DrawString("ü", wing, brush, _tickLeftPosition, _tickTopPosition);
                        }
                    }
                }
                pevent.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote above code. its working for me. But the problem here is everything like "box size ", "box location x and y", "text location x and y" ," tick location left and top" and "tick size" every thing I have created with properties to properly align everything.

Comment: while the font and the size of the checkbox is increased.